# Are heat sinks and radiators made of materials with high thermal conductance? Or low?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

Sorry to ask such a simple question, but I can't figure out if heat sinks and/or radiators should have high thermal conductivity or low....

If high, that would get the excess heat away from where you don't want it, but...

High thermal conductivity often means low specific heat capacity, right?  So the heat sink or radiator itself might overheat too quickly?

Perhaps they should combine both?

Comment: If a heat sink is becoming too hot then either the object it's cooling is running too hot or there is insufficient air/liquid flow from the material that the heat sink dumps the heat into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sorry to ask such a simple question, but I can't figure out if heat
> sinks and/or radiators should have high thermal conductivity or
> low....

It isn't really a simple question.

Let's take the 'simple' case of a [cooling fin](https://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/FALL/thermodynamics/notes/node128.html). At steady state (all temperatures are constant) the heat (power) $\dot{Q}$ carried off by the fin is given by:

$$\dot{Q}=\sqrt{kAhP}(T_0-T_{\infty})\tanh(mL)$$
where:
$$m=\frac{hP}{kA}$$

- $k$ is thermal conductivity and $h$ the convection heat transfer coefficient,
- $A$ the cross section and $P$ the fin's perimeter (e.g. $\pi R^2$ for a cylindrical fin),
- $T_0$ the temperature at the base of the fin (the temperature of the object to be cooled) and $T_{\infty}$ the surrounding, cool temperature.

So we can see the influence $k$ isn't straightforward. On the one hand: $\dot{Q} \propto \sqrt{k}$ but then on the other hand $k$ appears in the denominator of the $\tanh$ argument.

> High thermal conductivity often means low specific heat capacity,
> right?

No, there's no reason to believe that.

Answer (score 2):

"*High thermal conductivity often means low specific heat capacity, right?*" I don't know where you got this from.

You always want high thermal conductivity because it means you can make a bigger heatsink with more surface area to transfer heat to the air or water with since it can more efficiently conduct the heat to all regions.

A bonus is because you can use more material, you have more total thermal capacity to begin with even if the specific heat capacity of the material is lower.

You need both but thermal conductivity tends to be more important in real heatsinks because that's what actually gets rid of the heat. Specific heat capacity is just a buffer.

Comment: "*if the specific heat capacity is too low then the heatsink heats up more"* I don't know how you're obtaining this. At steady state, in all heat sink models I know of, the heat flux doesn't depend on the heat capacity at all. Perhaps you could review the model you're using.

Comment: @Chemomechanics I probably did not word it as precisely as I could have. I was more just trying to say that for same amount of thermal energy in it at equilibrium as heat flowed into it from the heat source and out of it into ambient, it would sit at a higher temperature than an identical heat sink of lower thermal capacity.

Comment: @Chemomechanics But now that you mention it, what you say is true about the models I use too. I'm not a heat expert and would not be surprised if higher temperature from lower thermal capacity somehow cancels itself out at steady state since the temperature gradient also determines the amount of heat flow.

Comment: Agreed. Could you also please add the math behind “*a material with zero specific heat capacity and infinite thermaly conductivity is worse than a material with zero thermal conductivity and infinite capacity because the former would have to be infinite size where the latter could be zero size.*”? I don’t understand why this is the case.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Actually, I flubbed there a lot. Zero thermal conductivity and infinite capacity would never be able to absorb heat from the heat sourcezero conductivity between heatsink and source. I was only thinking about internal heat distribution when I wrote that. You would need infinite contact area = infinite size in a way that is even worse than the first case's infinite size.